# Function being executed more than once

Tags: javascript

I am not able to discover the problem that is causing the function to be executed more than once.

The code snippet below is when the page is opened or when there has been a change, whether new or changed data. This function takes the data from the bank and shows, this part I will not show because it is unnecessary. After showing it, it calls two functions and it is the first one that is giving me a problem, the update function.

```
function carteProduct_listProducts() {
    let dataProductsDatas = document.getElementById("data_products_datas");

    firebase.database().ref("Products").on("value", snapshot => {
        dataProductsDatas.innerHTML = ""

        snapshot.forEach(element => {
            ...
        });

        // Edit buttons event listener
        // Update
        modalEditProduct()
        

        // Delete
        realtimedb_delete("Products");
    })
}
```

Then comes the update function, or as it is in the code, modalEditProduct.
I made a modal just for that, because I was having trouble using only one modal.
So, this function is called there in the other function. And I thought it was because of this that I was giving this problem, the function being executed twice, but no! I took the function out of there and tested it, but the problem keeps happening.

Then, when an edit button is clicked, the modal opens. So it performs some functions that are within that same function

```
// Update product
function modalEditProduct() {
    let editBtns = document.querySelectorAll("#data_products_datas .editBtn");
    let productTitleInput = document.querySelector("#modalEditProduct form input[name='productTitle']");
    let productCategoryInput = document.querySelector("#modalEditProduct form select[name='productCategory']");
    let productPriceInput = document.querySelector("#modalEditProduct form input[name='productPrice']");
    let productIngredientsInput = document.querySelector("#modalEditProduct form input[name='productIngredients']");
    let productDescriptionInput = document.querySelector("#modalEditProduct form input[name='productDescription']");
    let editSubmitBtn = document.querySelector("#modalEditProduct form button");
    console.log(editBtns)
    editBtns.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let key = e.target.id;
            // Open modal
            modal_openModal("modalEditProduct");
            
            // Get the data
            let data = getData(key);

            // putting categories on select
            cartePorudct_puttingCategoriesSelect(productCategoryInput);
            // let children = productCategoryInput.children;
            // console.log(children)
            // for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            //     const element = children[i];
            //     console.log(element)
            // }

            // Insert the data in the field/inputs
            setData(data);

            // Submit form
            editSubmitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
    
                realtimedb_verification("modalEditProduct", edit_productData, key)
            })
        })
    });

    // Get the data
    function getData(key) {
        let data;
        firebase.database().ref("Products/"+key).on("value", snapshot => {
            data = {
                title: snapshot.val().title,
                category: snapshot.val().category,
                price: snapshot.val().price,
                ingredients: snapshot.val().ingredients,
                description: snapshot.val().description,
            }
        });
        return data;
    }

    // Insert the data in the field/inputs
    function setData(data) {
        productTitleInput.value = data.title;
        // productCategoryInput.value = data.category,
        productPriceInput.value = data.price;
        productIngredientsInput.value = data.ingredients;
        productDescriptionInput.value = data.description;
    }

    // Submit form
    function submitForm(btn, key){
        
    }

    // Data
    function edit_productData(key) {
        let data = {
            title: productTitleInput.value,
            category: productCategoryInput.value,
            price: productPriceInput.value,
            ingredients: productIngredientsInput.value,
            description: productDescriptionInput.value,
        }

        // Update
        realtimedb_update("Products", key, data);
    }
}
```

Anyway, the problem is. When I open a modal, make a change and save, everything is fine. If I open the modal of another data, the previous data will also be changed with the value of that data after I click the submit button. And if I open a third modal, everything happens again.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `modalEditProduct()`, you add a new event listener to each of those `editBtns`.

That means that the first time you've called `modalEditProduct()` and click a button, it does its thing once. After a second call, the buttons now have two click event listeners, so clicking them will do a thing twice, etc.

Comment: Are you talking about me calling you in that first function? In that case, that is not the problem. I took it out and the problem still remains